# Encryption system in android

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I'd like to leave the user the possibility to choice the encryption method, but for now I implemented just **AES** with *SHA1PRNG*. With *AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding* it doesn't work.
What does other encryption method work with android?
I have to encrypt data to store them in a db and then decrypt for show them.

The error returned:
*java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SecureRandom AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding implementation not found*
here:

```
SecureRandom.getInstance( "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" );
```

Comment: http://www.bouncycastle.org provides most all of common crypto algorithms in plain Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use a random number generator (which is what SecureRandom is for), or do you want to use an encryption algorithm (which is what AES is for)?

If you want an encryption algorithm (and its implementation), use the `javax.crypto.Cipher` class, which should support your `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` algorithm.

In principle you can use AES to build an RNG, too, but then you would not use `CBC/PKCS5Padding`, but something like ANSI X9.31. I don't think this is implemented in any Java and/or Android API for SecureRandom.

Comment: I already use _javax.crypto.Cipher_ in the class to encrypt strings!

Comment: So what are you doing with SecureRandom then? (You can edit your question to put your code, if this makes it clearer.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the reference it only supports SHA1PRNG, unless you install other providers.
See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/SecureRandom.html